# Анимация перекрывает анимацию передвижения кнопки

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Добавил анимацию, которая уходит влево и вправо. Она работает, но после того как первый раз я перемещаешь объект анимация передвижения есть, НО после 1 раза работает только анимация. Подскажите в чем проблема! Заранее спасибо.

```
public partial class Switcher : Window
    {
        public Switcher()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        bool Action = false;

        double   InitPxls = 15;
        double FinitePxls = 420;
        double Movement;

        Point Point;

        private void CircleKnob_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Action = true;
            Point = Mouse.GetPosition(CircleKnob);
            Mouse.Capture(CircleKnob);
        }

        private void CircleKnob_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Action)
            {
                Movement = Canvas.GetLeft(CircleKnob) + Mouse.GetPosition(CircleKnob).X - Point.X;

                if (Movement > InitPxls && Movement < FinitePxls) {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(CircleKnob,   Movement);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(CircleShadow, Movement - 15);
                }
            }
        }

        private void CircleKnob_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Action = false;
            Mouse.Capture(null);

            Storyboard  ToInite = this.FindResource("EllipseIniteKnob") as Storyboard;
            Storyboard ToFinite = this.FindResource("EllipseFiniteKnob") as Storyboard;


            Storyboard  ToIniteShadow = this.FindResource("EllipseIniteShadow") as Storyboard;
            Storyboard ToFiniteShadow = this.FindResource("EllipseFiniteShadow") as Storyboard;

            if (Movement < InitPxls + 210)
            {
                Canvas.SetLeft(CircleKnob, InitPxls);
                Canvas.SetLeft(CircleShadow, InitPxls - 15);

                BeginStoryboard(ToInite);
                BeginStoryboard(ToIniteShadow);
            }
            else
            {
                Canvas.SetLeft(CircleKnob, FinitePxls);
                Canvas.SetLeft(CircleShadow, FinitePxls - 15);

                BeginStoryboard(ToFinite);
                BeginStoryboard(ToFiniteShadow);
            }
        }
    }
```

Анимация:

```
<!--ANIMATED ELLIPSES TO CORNERS-->
    <Storyboard x:Key="EllipseIniteKnob" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)">
        <DoubleAnimation To="15" Duration="00:00:4" Storyboard.TargetName="CircleKnob">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <ElasticEase Oscillations="1" 
                             Springiness="27" 
                             EasingMode="EaseOut">
                </ElasticEase>
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="EllipseFiniteKnob" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)">
        <DoubleAnimation To="420" Duration="00:00:4" Storyboard.TargetName="CircleKnob">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <ElasticEase Oscillations="1" 
                             Springiness="27" 
                             EasingMode="EaseOut">
                </ElasticEase>
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>


    <Storyboard x:Key="EllipseIniteShadow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)">
        <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="00:00:4" Storyboard.TargetName="CircleShadow">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <ElasticEase Oscillations="1" 
                             Springiness="27" 
                             EasingMode="EaseOut">
                </ElasticEase>
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="EllipseFiniteShadow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)">
        <DoubleAnimation To="405" Duration="00:00:4" Storyboard.TargetName="CircleShadow">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <ElasticEase Oscillations="1" 
                             Springiness="27" 
                             EasingMode="EaseOut">
                </ElasticEase>
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
```

Comment: Я не добавлял код анимации, потому что проблема не в ней. Если в коде я убираю BeginStoryboard, то пользователь может перемещать кнопку и видить как она ходит по оси Х. Я добавил условие, что если кнопку опускаю до 210 пх она возвращается влево, но так как она некрасиво и резко возврощается в край, я решил доабвить анимацию. Но теперь когда я добавляю анимацию BeginStoryboard(), первое действие с кнопкой - вижу как она двигается, но в след разы, она просто перемешается без анимации перемещения(простите за тофтологию).